# Mulesoft vCore metric

Tags: performance, mule, monitoring, cloudhub

I would like to get data about the APIs.

More specifically: how many vCores are assigned and what is the load on those vCores. So for example, if I assign 1 vCore to an API but it is barely used, that would be a waste.

So I want to build an API that would get me this data and transform it into a suitable format. Can someone tell me, how can I get this data about APIs and if that is even possible to do.

so what I want to return is something like this:

---

api-name, vCoreUsed, Load%

appOne, 2, 50%

---

(What I mean by load: so if the load is 100% it means that all vCores are used and the service might be slow and if it is 10% than it is a waste of vCores)

Thank you for all replies (and I hope it makes sense what I said ;/ )

Comment: there is no stupid question. 
Please be more careful in your explanation and give more context what exactly want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is more related to [Cloudhub Architecture](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-architecture). Please refer to [Cloudhub Architecture](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-architecture) and [cloudhub fabric](http://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-api) and [features](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-fabric#enabling-cloudhub-fabric-features) for the details.

(As per Mule documentation)

CloudHub Workers
Applications on CloudHub are run by one or more instances of Mule, called workers. These have the following characteristics:

Capacity: Each worker has a specific amount of capacity to process data, you can select the size of your workers when configuring an application.

Isolation: Each worker runs in a separate container from every other application.

Manageability: Each worker is deployed and monitored independently.

Locality: Each worker runs in a specific worker cloud, the US, EU, Asia-Pacific, etc.

Each worker is a dedicated instance of Mule that runs your integration application. Workers may have a different memory capacity and processing power depending on how you configure them at application level. Workers can be scaled vertically by selecting one of the available worker sizes:

Worker Sizes:

0.1 vCores + 500 MB Heap Memory

0.2 vCores + 1 GB Heap Memory

1 vCores + 1.5 GB Heap Memory

2 vCores + 3.5 GB Heap Memory

4 vCores + 7.5 GB Heap Memory

8 vCores + 15 GB Heap Memory

16 vCores + 32 GB Heap Memory

Comment: Thank you for you reply, the cloudhub API seems what I am looking for